# Rspec for conditional filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have one controller as follow.

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, except: [:forgot_password]

end
```

What is the rspec for before filters with expect condition

I did like this

```
describe 'response of filters' do

  describe 'there are no authentication required ' do
    it "before forgot_password" do
      controller.stub(:action_name){ :forgot_password }
      should_not use_before_filter(:authenticate_admin!)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I got error like below

```
 Failure/Error: should_not use_before_filter(:authenticate_admin!)
 Expected that AdminsController would not have :authenticate_admin! as a before_filter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the documentation, and it is clear that the shoulda-matchers do not support conditional before-filters.

I generally do not test before-filters like that. I have two approaches:

- or I test that I can reach the page when using a specific user, and not with another
- or I test that the before-filter function is called

So in your case I would do something like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminsController do 

  it { should use_before_filter(:authenticate_admin!) }

  it "allows unauthenticated access for forgot_password" do 
    controller.should_not_receive(:authenticate_admin!)
    get :forgot_password
  end
end
```

Comment: I stub action, because filters is evoking according to action_name, so I have set action name using stubbing, and check that 'authenticate_admin!' filter should not run for 'forget_password' method.

Comment: I did not completely understand at first. The `use_before_filter` matcher does not support conditional filters, so stubbing will have no effect. I adapted my answer.

Comment: Thanks Nathanvda, Its working fine :)
but can you clarify me why you check 'controller.should_not_receive(:authenticate_admin!)' before the action call ?

Comment: It expresses an expectation, which is only checked afterwards (the same as `should_receive`, but then explicitly testing it is NOT called). You have to "register" that rspec needs to watch this method before actually doing the `get`. Is that clear?